# PingFederate is not sending back relayState in its response

Tags: saml-2.0, pingfederate

I am using PingFederate as a Idenity Provider. My application(Service Provider) sends RelayState to PingFederate. But on successful authentication, I am not getting the RelayState back.

By RelayState, my understanding is that its the state information which the ServiceProvider will need on successful authentication at the PingFederation end.

Please correct me If I am wrong.

Answer (score 0):

What version of PingFederate are you on?

Since you're getting relay state from the SP, you should be seeing an AuthNRequest posted to your PingFed endpoint.

You can use Firefox with SSO-Tracer or SAML-Tracer to validate you're getting a relay state posted to Ping and view the response going back.

Answer (score -3):

PingFederate seems to be dealing with RelayState in a different but non-standard way. Following is the link for reference :

[https://documentation.pingidentity.com/pingfederate/pf84/index.shtml#concept_idpEndpoints.html](http://docs.oasis-open.org/security/saml/v2.0/)

Optional Parameter TargetResource or TARGET in the IdPEndPoint URL as parameter. The value of this must be a URL and URL Encoded.

The is different from what the SAML2 Specification http://docs.oasis-open.org/security/saml/v2.0/

I am using HTTP POST binding  and this is what the spec says for

> 3.5.3 RelayState
>
> RelayState data MAY be included with a SAML protocol message
>   transmitted with this binding. The value MUST NOT exceed 80 bytes in
>   length and SHOULD be integrity protected by the entity creating the
>   message independent of any other protections that may or may not exist
>   during message transmission. Signing is not realistic given the space
>   limitation, but because the value is exposed to third-party tampering,
>   the entity SHOULD ensure that the value has not been tampered with by
>   using a checksum, a pseudo-random value, or similar means. If a SAML
>   request message is accompanied by RelayState data, then the SAML
>   responder MUST return its SAML protocol response using a binding that
>   also supports a RelayState mechanism, and it MUST place the exact data
>   it received with the request into the corresponding RelayState
>   parameter in the response. If no such value is included with a SAML
>   request message, or if the SAML response message is being generated
>   without a corresponding request, then the SAML responder MAY include
>   RelayState data to be interpreted by the recipient based on the use of
>   a profile or prior agreement between the parties.

WSO2 seems to echo whatever we send to it as a RelayState value.

BTW I am using PingFederate 8.2.11.

Comment: That is not the correct endpoint you're looking at - the page you have linked to is for IdP Application Endpoints which are indeed PingFederate proprietary and intended for custom apps to bridge to it. The SAML protocol endpoint (documented here: https://documentation.pingidentity.com/pingfederate/pf84/index.shtml#concept_viewingProtocolEndpoints.html) is standard and will echo RelayState went presented with it.

Comment: Scott's correct - you're talking about the application endpoint, not the protocol endpoint. PingFederate is, and has been, protocol compliant for years.

Comment: Thanks for the valuable feedback. I will look into it and update the thread accordingly